# Ember: setting controller properties in init()?

Tags: ember.js

Having a hard time figuring out why controller properties added in `init()` are added as '`undefined`' rather than with default values.  I guess you're supposed to define in `init()` to avoid "[leaking state](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/09/18/ember-best-practices-avoid-leaking-state-into-factories)"?  I think I am missing something fundamental here.

When a controller property like an empty array is specified right on the controller it's added as '`Array[0]`', which then allows you to `pushObject` stuff into it.  When added in `init()` they are added as '`undefined`' so `pushObject` fails.

See demo on this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/fb1680bfea201aeb4a0d886aafa3eed5?openFiles=controllers.results.js%2C&route=%2Fresults%3Ffilter2%3D%255B%2522Value%2520of%2520Filter%25202%2522%255D%26q%3Dfoo) and/or the code below:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    queryParams: ['q','sort_method','search_type','filter1','filter2'],

    init(){
        this._super(...arguments);

        Ember.set(this, 'q', null);
        Ember.set(this, 'sort_method', 'relevance'); // <-- sets default value to 'undefined'
        Ember.set(this, 'filter1', []); // <-- sets default value to 'undefined'
    },

  filter2: [], // <-- sets default values properly but will it cause state issues?
  search_type: 'bar'

});
```

Basically, I'm wanting to figure out how to declare my list of query params in ONE place (like in config file), rather than 3 places (route, controller queryParams array, and to the controller itself)

I created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b82c69819c5eb51171c6724960f880fe?openFiles=templates.results.hbs%2C) to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

> why controller properties added in init() are added as 'undefined'

If you dig deep into ember sources, you will find a lot of code in Ember.Route that "prepare" query parameters to work (for example, you may try to analyze [this code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.11.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L171)). I guess that answer to this question is somewhere in route's code (probably route initialize properties before/after controller's init is called or something like that).

> Basically, I'm wanting to figure out how to declare my list of query params in ONE place (like in config file), rather than 3 places (route, controller queryParams array, and to the controller itself)

You can declare parameters in environment.js. Then, in controller import it and pass to Ember.Controller.extend

```
import ENV from 'project-name/config/environment';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.$.extend({}, ENV.myDefaults.controller, {
  actions: {
    addFilter: function(key, value) {
      alert(`adding "${value.toString()}" to controller property '${key}'`);
      console.log("DUMP OF EMBER 'this':", this);
      this[key].pushObject(value.toString());
    }     
  } 
}));
```

[See twiddle for details](https://ember-twiddle.com/4a58aeddefe729b2299d0d26b0d11f21?openFiles=controllers.results.js%2C&route=%2Fresults%3Ffilter1%3D%255B%2522Value%2520of%2520Filter%25201%2522%255D%26filter2%3D%255B%2522Value%2520of%2520Filter%25202%2522%255D%26q%3Dfoo)